# What keys are generated during Debian 7.4 (Wheezy) installation?

Tags: security, encryption

We are concerned lest `/dev/random` (or `/dev/urandom`) be hit too early in the installation process for adequate entropy to be developed. In a basic Debian 7.4 installation (SSH Server and basic utilities only) are any keys, fingerprints, etc. generated before the SSH host key?

Comment: With what package selections?  Can you just go inspect `/var/lib/dpkg/info/*.(preinst|postinst)` for your package selection.

Comment: With the selection "SSH Server" and "Standard" - we're aware that a ssh host key is generated near the end of the installation process. Our question is whether other keys are generated, particularly earlier in the installation process when there may be less entropy available to /dev/urandom. IOW, are any keys generated *before* the package selection process? Are there any calls to /dev/random or /dev/urandom earlier in the installation process?

Comment: The only one I know of is `/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` for the ssl package. After that is up to each packages.